# Route changes but view doesn't ui-router

Tags: angularjs, authentication, redirect, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to redirect unauthorized people when they first enter my website via a url;

`eg: example.com/#/order` should be redirected to `example.com/#/auth`, this includes when they first visit the webpage and also navigating inbetween states.

Currently I have an abstract parent state of `/order` and `/auth` which have resolves that check for authentication and redirect otherwise. I also have a watch on the `$stateChangeStart` event to do the same thing.

The code for when you initially load the page works correctly, it will redirect if you visit `/order/restaurant` without being logged in, however if I'm on the url `/auth/login` I can change my url to `/order/resturant` and it will redirect me successful but the view will not update. I will still be able to see the `/order/resturant` page but the resolve and page changes were hit. Why does this happen? I've attempted to use `$rootScope.$apply()` without success as well.

My code is as follows for the parent states:

```
// Authentication Urls
.state('auth', {
  url: '/auth',
  templateUrl: 'modules/auth/auth.html',
  abstract: true
})

// Order Urls
.state('order', {
  url: '/order',
  templateUrl: 'modules/order/order.html',
  abstract: true
})
```

and my code to watch the stateChange

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'Auth', function($rootScope, $state, Auth) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {
    var stateName = toState.name
    console.log('State start')

    if (!stateName.match(/auth/) && !Auth.isLoggedIn) {
      console.log('User is not visiting auth and isn\'t logged in, redirecting....')
      $state.go('auth.login')

    } else if (Auth.isLoggedIn && stateName.match(/auth/)) {
      console.log('User is logged in and is on the auth page, redirecting....')
      $state.go('order.resturant')
    }
  })
}])
```

Comment: Why use both the resolve approach and the statechangestart? Can you not just remove the resolve code from your routes and in your statechangestart code simply perform your $state.go('auth') if the user is not logged in and already requesting the auth page? Shouldn't need anything other than that.

Comment: Also location.path afaik doesn't fire any route events hence nothing in the view changes.

Comment: In the run method of yiur angular app module you can perform redirect in there for when the page first loads.

Comment: Your right about that, I'll try and check back

Comment: Well I removed the resolves which worked well so thank you, now the problem still lies with the page not changing the $state.go doesn't actually change the page, the url is changed but the controller still runs and the view doesn't change.

Comment: I don't see an order.restaurant state in your routes. If the url is changing and the controller firing then your issue lies in your html at a guess..

Comment: Looking at the documentation here (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events) you should cancel the navigation by calling `event.preventDefault()` before performing your new transition. See if that helps?

Comment: No problem. I'll post as an answer if you wouldn't mind marking as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation here (http://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events) you should cancel the navigation by calling `event.preventDefault()` before performing your new transition.